# Ionic / AngularJS base64 image won't display

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to simply display a base64 image in an Ionic app.

The image won't display if I do this:

HTML:

```
 <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{myImage}}"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myImage= "/9j/4AAQSkZJ ...";
```

But the image WILL display if I just put the encoded string directly in the image element like this:

```
 <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ ..."/>
```

I have checked every unsafe security setting, looked at dozens of other SO posts, etc. If I put this small example in a CodePen, it works both ways.

What could be happening to the `$scope.myImage` variable that would prevent it from binding to the image element? Is it an ionic thing? An angular issue?

Comment: Here's what the HTML looks like when served: `<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,">`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `data-ng-src` directive like this `<img data-ng-src="{{data.image_url}}">`.

In your controller set base64 string as this:
`$scope.data.image_url=<your base64 image source>`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, solved it by configuring the main angular module with whitelisting this way:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https|ftp|mailto|file|tel|data)/);})
```

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes I too face the issue, and use `setTimeout` or `$timeout`.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $scope.myImage= "/9j/4AAQSkZJ ...";
}, 2000);
```

In Angular way (add `$timeout`  DI in controller)-

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.myImage= "/9j/4AAQSkZJ ...";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Interesting thought, but the timer had no effect.

Comment: @lilbiscuit Can you please paste your base64 encoded data ?

Comment: I have determined that there's a conflict somewhere in my app. If I start with a blank project I don't have this problem.

Answer (score -3):

just use `ng-if` at the div, and then the img tag gets rendered as soon as the data is loaded