# How to display image stored in postgre db (as base64) in ionic 4 page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, base64, ionic4

Hello I have spring boot application in my table I store image as byte [] arr. Via the get request I send the my result to the ionic app to the display. However in it does not display image.

Here is the code,
`

## Java Spring Boot (Model)

```
 @Column(name = "image")
    public byte []getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(byte [] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

## Java Spring Boot Controller

```
 @GetMapping("/drivers/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Drivers> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long driverId)
            throws Exception {
        Drivers employee = driverRepository.findById(driverId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Employee not found for this id :: " + driverId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(employee);
    }
```

## Angular/Ionic

```
etchAlarms(){
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/getAllDrivers')
    .subscribe(transformedData =>{
      this.alarmsChanged.next(transformedData);
    });
  }
```

## HTML

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{alarms.image}}"/>
```

I read almost all the question related this, but unfortunately I couldnt solve the problem.

Here is some of the related questions I have checked;

[How to display base64 image on iPhone in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243999/how-to-display-base64-image-on-iphone-in-ionic-4)

[How to display image in ionic 4 using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427414/how-to-display-image-in-ionic-4-using-angular-js)

[Base64 encoded image is not displaying in ionic framework apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312408/base64-encoded-image-is-not-displaying-in-ionic-framework-apps)

[Ionic / AngularJS base64 image won't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977110/ionic-angularjs-base64-image-wont-display)

## Thank You very much. Any help is appreciated

## EDIT

Here is error from chrome console

```
unsafe:data:image/png;base64,:1 GET unsafe:data:image/png;base64, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Comment: can you elaborate - what errors you see? how sure you are that the service call (getAllDrivers) returns actual base64 string?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a Java byte array for an image is not the same thing as a base64 encoded image. You may find some help encoding and decoding the byte array in Java with this post: https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

I also saw a stack exchange tip showing this as a solution:

`encodedfile = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "UTF-8");`

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I added the error.

Comment: @CodyBurleson  I store images in the postgree db, and my colomn type in postgre db is bytea. So what should I do ? Should I store images as an String in db ?

Comment: @ozer It seems to me that when Java methods like `encodedfile = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes), "UTF-8");` are available, you should be able to continue storing your image in the database as bytes. You just need to make the conversion from the bytes to Base64 by the time your reach the view layer for image rendering. This could happen in the getter method of the service that accesses the database (e.g. `getImageBytesAsBase64()` ) or in the controller that sits between the service and the view, or in a helper class that multiple controllers use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## .TS

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer)
```

Add this to your angular/ionic

## HTML

```
<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,'+alarms.image)"width="50%" height="50%" alt="Image"/>
```

Add this line to your HTML.

It will work.